# Naming BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to be able to name a BackgroundWorker to make it easier to debug.  Is this possible?

Comment: As Jonathan noted in the comment on the accepted answer, this presents a *real* risk of causing confusion, by putting a name on a thread that is later re-used for something else. It isn't your thread; don't attempt to name it. If you want a named thread, create your own (rather than using `BackgroundWorker`).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I'd have to try but can't you just set the [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.name.aspx) of the thread in the DoWork() method executed by the BackgroundWorker?

UPDATE: I just tried the following line of code as the first statement of my BackgroundWorkers DoWork() method and it works:

```
if (Thread.CurrentThread.Name == null)
    Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "MyBackgroundWorkerThread";
```

UPDATE: As Jonathan Allen correctly stated the name of a thread is write once, so I added a null check before setting the name. An attempt to write the name for the second time would result in an InvalidOperationException. As Marc Gravell wrote it might also make debugging **harder** as soon as pooled background threads are re-used for other work, so name threads only if necessary..

Comment: I think that is dangerous. You can only set the name on a thread once, but the threads that background workers use may be reused.

Comment: I agree with @Jonathan - if it isn't your thread, you shouldn't be naming it.

Comment: Usually there are so many unnamed threads that just setting the name to a generic "BackgroundWorker" seems useful. Thanks for the tip, going to try it.

Answer (score 15):

```
public class NamedBackgroundWorker : BackgroundWorker
{
    public NamedBackgroundWorker(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Thread.CurrentThread.Name == null) // Can only set it once
            Thread.CurrentThread.Name = Name;

        base.OnDoWork(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just checked with Reflector. BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync uses thread-pool threads. Since a thread's name can only be set once, your code will throw an exception if you happen to use the same threadpool thread twice.

Comment: .NET 4.0 uses a nested type "private delegate void WorkerThreadStartDelegate(object argument);"
And they call BeginInvoke on it, so as far as I can see they don't use the ThreadPool, but you are correct, I should have checked if the Name was null before setting it.

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the background worker through a custom class:

`

```
public class NamedBackgroundWorker : BackgroundWorker
{

     public string Name;

     public BackgroundWorker(string Name)
     {
       this.Name = Name;
     }
}
```

`
Now just create an object from this and you can name it and use it as a background worker.

Comment: This answer is the same as the earlier answer of XIU, but with a tiny bit better explination

Answer (score 0):

You can name your threads in the "Threads"-window when you are debugging in Visual Studio.